# GCD vs @synchronized vs NSLock

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety

Can someone give a rundown of the benefits and drawbacks of these 3 systems in how they relate to thread safety?

From watching more recent WWDC videos, I get the feeling that Apple is pushing the usage of GCD to create performant reader-writer that are thread safe.

What's the idea/backing behind this? Is it the time to access a lock having to enter the kernel that leads to this GCD push, and shying away from @synchronized and NSLock?

Are @synchronized and NSLock being pushed out of what would be considered best practice, or is there still a place for them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many many details that could be discussed at great length in regards to this.  But, at the core:

These always require a lock to be taken somewhere or somehow:

```
@synchronized(...) { ... }
[lock lock];
```

Locks are very expensive for the reasons you mention;  they necessarily consume kernel resources.   (The @synchronized() case actually may avoid kernel locks these days, but it is a hash based exclusion mechanism and that, in itself, is expensive).

And these do not always require a lock (but sometimes maybe do):

```
dispatch_sync(...concurrent q...., ^{ ... });
dispatch_async(...queue of any kind...., ^{ ... });
```

There is a fast path through the dispatch functions that are effectively lockless (though they will use test-and-set atomic primitives that can cause performance issues under load).

The end result is that a synchronous dispatch to a concurrent queue can effectively be treated as "execute this on this thread right now".   A synchronous dispatch to a serial queue can do the atomic test-and-set to test if the queue is processing, mark it as busy, and, if it wasn't busy, execute the block  on the calling thread immediately.

Asynchronous dispatches can be similarly as fast, though asynchronous dispatch requires copying the block (which can be very cheap, but something to think about).

In general, GCD can do anything a lock can do, can do it at least -- if not more -- efficiently, and you can use the GCD APIs to go way beyond just simple locking (using a semaphore as a computation throttle, for example).

BTW:  If your tasks are relatively coarse grained, have a look at `NSOperationQueue` and `NSOperation`.